# Get Google Cloud Storage File from ObjectName

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm migrating my GAE app from the deprecated File API to Google Cloud Storage Client Library. 
I used to persist the blobKey, but since there is partial support for it (as specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/)) from now on I'll have to persist the object name.
Unfortunately the object name that comes from the GCS looks more or less like this

> /gs/bucketname/819892hjd81dh19gf872g8211

as you can see, it also contains the bucket name

Here's the issue, every time I need to get the file for further processing (or to serve it in a servlet) I need to create an instance of GcsFileName(bucketName, objectName) which gives me something like

> /bucketName/gs/bucketName/akahsdjahslagfasgfjkasd

which (of course) doesn't work.

so. my question is:
 - how can I generate a GcsFileName form the objectName?

UPDATE

I tried using the objectName as BlobKey. But it just doesn't work :(

```
InputStream is = new BlobstoreInputStream(blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey("/gs/bucketName/akahsdjahslagfasgfjkasd"));
```

I got the usual answer

> BlobstoreInputStream received an invalid blob key

How do I get the file using the ObjectName???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have persisted and retrieved e.g the string `String objname` worth e.g `"/gs/bucketname/819892hjd81dh19gf872g8211"`, you could split it on "/" (`String[] pieces = objname.split("/")`) and use the pieces appropriately in the call to `GcsFileName`.

Comment: That's what I did eventually. I have to say I was expecting a better API for such an important feature. Thanks for your help

Comment: In Python one uses `os.path.dirname` and `os.path.basename` rather than just splitting the strings, but my Java-fu is weak so I don't know the Java equivalents (I also expect like you that Java's huge standard library offers a better, i.e more elegant, API for this important feature of splitting paths into dirname and basename -- just like Python's stdlib does; of course this isn't really about GCS, it's about file paths in general, so it should surely be in the standard library -- maybe another Q just about Java will get Java expert help!-).  BTW, why no accept...?